# Jenkins and Python

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to run Python job which I configured on Jenkins to run , it runs good till I want to pass variables, what I have to do in order to pass variables via Jenkins with command shell? what do I have to add for the job and what changes I have to make in the script itself?

thanks,

Erez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Jenkins daily and run Python scripts from Jenkins jobs. Here are some examples of how I call Python scripts with parameters:

```
python ./local_lib/bin/regression.py -u daily_regression
python ./local_lib/bin/run.py -t $Test_Name -b -c -no_compile -no_wlf
python ./local_lib/bin/run.py -t $Test_Name -b -c -no_compile -no_wlf -args="$sim_args"
python ./local_lib/bin/results.py  -r daily_regression -html  -o $WORK/results/daily_regression_results.html
```

Is this what you want?

You should use the "This build is parameterized" option from the Jenkins job configuration panel. I added a String Parameter with the name "Test_Name" which I then use in the "Execute Shell" text area like this $Test_Name

And here is how to use it in the Python script. Let's take the Python script call:

```
python ./local_lib/bin/run.py -t $Test_Name -b -c -no_compile -no_wlf
```

The script run.py may be:

```
import sys

print "Number of arguments", len(sys.argv)
for arg in sys.argv :
    print arg

# or

print 'second method'

for i in range(len(sys.argv)) :
    print sys.argv[i]

# take the test name given by the Jenkins parameter $Test_Name
testName = sys.argv[2] # arg 0 is script name, arg 1 == '-t', arg 2 == '<the provided test name in Jenkins Run Job interface as a string>', ...
print testName
```

Output is:

```
E:\>python run.py -t $Test_Name -b -c -no_compile -no_wlf
Number of arguments 7
run.py
-t
$Test_Name
-b
-c
-no_compile
-no_wlf
second method
jenkins.py
-t
$Test_Name
-b
-c
-no_compile
-no_wlf
$Test_Name
```

I do not have access to Jenkins on the PC am I now, so in this case $Test_Name was printed as it is, but on Jenkins it would have been replaced by the name user provided in the textbox when started the Jenkins job.

Comment: How do you use inside your script? I have done something like this:

# Accuracy parameters in minutes
time_threshold = sys.argv[1]

import detection

result = dict()
users_with_neura_events = 0
users_with_timeline_events = 0

print time_threshold
total = len(sys.argv)

where i take the first argument and assign it to my variable.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example. If still not clear, please provide a concrete code and state what it is not working. Thank you.